# If $\alpha(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}I(x - \frac{1}{n})$ stuck evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} xd\alpha$ Where I is the unit step function

Tags: real-analysis

I've turned this into a Riemann integral and evaluated to the point where I have $$x\alpha(x)|^{1}_{0} - \int_{0}^{1}\alpha(x)dx$$ and I have already figured out that $x\alpha(x)|^{1}_{0} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - 1$ but I don't know how to evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1}\alpha(x)dx$.

I saw a graph of it so it would be something like $$(1- \frac{1}{2})(\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-1-\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{3})(\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-1-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{9})+\cdots+0$$ but I can't find a closed form that adds up to a number. Is there a way to take this integral with a number as the answer? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please define the function $I(u)$ appeariong in the title.

Comment: Changing the order of summation and integration gives that $\int_0^1\alpha(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}\int_{1/n}^1\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}(1-1/n)$. However, we don't know the exact value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}$.....

Comment: I see, how do you get from step 2 to step 3?

Comment: @DicapriosWife2541 We need to calculate the integral $\int_0^1 I(x-1/n)\,dx$, which is exactly $\int_{1/n}^1 1\,dx=1-1/n$.